# Why can't I import urlpatterns from urls.py?

Tags: python, django, import, url-pattern

I am trying to create a simple Django view that will render a list of links to all of the other views in my app.

my plan was to simply import my list of urlpatterns from urls.py like this

```
from urls import urlpatterns
```

and then generate a list of names like this

```
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    context={"urlnames":[]}
    for up in urlpatterns:
        context["urlnames"].append(up.name)
    return render_to_response('api_list.html', context)
```

and then render them like this

```
{% for urlname in urlnames %}
<div>
  <a href='{% url urlname %}' > {{urlname}} </a>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

But python cant import urlpatterns at import time. If I try to do it later, by putting the import statement in my get request, then it works fine, but why doesn't it work at import time?

Comment: Circular import is happening! Putting import statement inside a function is called "defer importing".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Circular import is happening! Import module as `import urls` and get `urlpatterns` like this:

```
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    context={"urlnames":[]}
    for up in urls.urlpatterns:
        context["urlnames"].append(up.name)
    return render_to_response('api_list.html', context)
```